# Cross-validation gives unexpected results on Boston Housing without shuffling

Tags: scikit-learn

I am getting surprising results for Boston Housing.  The following code produces very different results when I apply cross-validation to the original Boston Housing dataset and to its randomly shuffled version:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
boston = load_boston()
knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)
print(cross_val_score(knn, boston.data, boston.target))
X, y = shuffle(boston.data, boston.target, random_state=0)
print(cross_val_score(knn, X, y))
```

The output is:

```
[-1.07454938 -0.50761407  0.00351173]
[0.30715435 0.36369852 0.51817514]
```

Even if the order of the original dataset is not random, why are the 1 Nearest Neighbor predictions so poor for it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the original dataset is not random at all.  Since I do not normalize the dataset, two features essentially determine the Euclidean distances: feature 9 (with mean around 408) and feature 11 (mean around 357); I think these are PTRATIO (pupil-teacher ratio by town) and LSTAT (% lower status of the population).  The graph of PTRATIO is

[image: feature 9].

Roughly the last third of all samples have very high values of this feature; so the third fold (and scikit-learn uses 3 folds by default) is highly anomalous.  The graph for LSTAT looks less striking, but nevertheless the last third is still highly anomalous.  So it's not surprising that the 1NN results are so poor without shuffling.